# escaping entire urls for use in regex commands

Tags: bash, url, variables, escaping, applescript

I'm having a little trouble with escaping in Applescript and shell scripts. Basically, a URL will be set as variableUrl, and this will be fed into a shell script:

```
do shell script "cd dir; cat file | grep -v '^http' | sed 's/^/" & variableUrl & "/' > urlsxy.txt"
```

This isn't working — I get nothing in my output file. The issue, I think, is that there are unescaped characters. Worse, I can't know ahead of time how the URL will look, and thus I can't set up any way to put backslashes in as escapes. When, instead of using `variableUrl`, I just insert dummy text, I have no problem. This, for example, works fine:

```
do shell script "cd dir; cat file | grep -v '^http' | sed 's/^/dummytext/' > urlsxy.txt"
```

Just now, I have also tried turning the url into a bash variable and doing ...

```
sed 's/^/"$BASHVAR\\/g
```

but this fails as well, for presumably the same reason. Can any body tell me if there is a workaround for this problem, or if there is a way of escaping an entire variable without knowing in advance what its content will be?

I'm very new at this, and as you can see am only familiar with the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to replace this symbol "^", then this should work:

```
sed "s/\^/`printf '%q' "${BASHVAR}"`/g"
```

Or, to insert the content of $BASHVAR at the beginning of each line:

```
sed "s/^/`printf '%q' "${BASHVAR}"`/g"
```

NOTE: The backticks (`) around the printf statement are important, since they tell the shell to execute and get the result of :

```
printf '%q' "${BASHVAR}"
```

EDIT: To consider the additional restriction (see comments to this answer) that a forward slash may appear in $BASHVAR, then an alternative solution is to use a character different that the forward slash as the separator for sed. Two examples:

```
sed "s@^@`printf '%q' "${BASHVAR}"`@g"
sed "s#^#`printf '%q' "${BASHVAR}"`#g"
```

Comment: No luck. I was actually trying to insert the $BASHVAR at the beginning of every line. I tried 'sed -i.bak "s/^/`printf '%q' ${BASHVAR}`/"' but all my results came out as: `printf %q ${BASHVAR}`/search.php
`printf %q ${BASHVAR}`register.php?ref=notice_debate

Comment: You are missing the backticks "`".

Comment: Ok, nearly there. When I do your script exactly, I get: 'sed: 1: "s/^/http://www.studentr ...": bad flag in substitute command: '/'' . If I take the forward slashes out of the variable, the output works. So the forward slashes aren't being escaped, it seems. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a character that you know won't appear in the string? For example, if you know "@" will never appear in your string, then this should work: `sed "s@^@\`printf '%q' ${BASHVAR}\`@g"`

Comment: I have no idea how this works, but dude, you are my hero. This has been driving me crazy. If you want to post this as an answer, I'll give you the big tick.

Comment: You also have to quote the variable after %q to prevent word splitting.

Comment: @LauriRanta: Thanks, I just fixed my solution accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

awk supports passing variables with -v:

```
v=\'\"\$'  '; awk -v v="$v" '!/^http/{print v$0}' file > urlsxy.txt
```

The first argument for gsub is a regex, but you can escape it or use another scripting language

```
$ echo a. | awk -v v=. '{gsub(v,"y")}1'
yy
$ echo a. | awk -v v=\\\\. '{gsub(v,"y")}1'
ay
$ echo a. | v=. ruby -pe '$_.gsub! ENV["v"], "y"'
ay
```

In this case you could also do something like this:

`do shell script "while IFS= read -r l; do [[ $l = http* ]] || printf %s " & quoted form of variableUrl & "\"$l\"; done < /tmp/file"`

Comment: Thanks a ton for this. I just started learning a couple of weeks ago, and find myself doing all possible things in sed just because I understand it. With your examples I can really start branching out.